# Javascript sort array of objects by a boolean property

Tags: javascript, sorting

***See edit at end for actual problem.***

Ok, I have this scenario:

```
a = [false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

Then if I do this:

```
a.sort(function(a,b){return !a && b});
```

It gives me this:

```
[false, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

It's sorta doing a sort... but not quite... :(

How do I sort this array?

EDIT:

***If you are wondering why I did not use just a.sort() is because my actual array is of objects, not a plain array like the one I posted. The real one has elements that look like [{xx:true},{xx:false},...]***

Comment: If I do a.map(function(x){ return x?1:0 }).sort(function(a,b){return a>b}); does not work either... I think I might be doing something elementary wrong

Comment: why you need to write custom function? a.sort() should work

Comment: is there are a way using lodash

Answer (score 343, accepted):

```js
a = [false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false];
    
    
    a.sort(function(x, y) {
        // true values first
        return (x === y)? 0 : x? -1 : 1;
        // false values first
        // return (x === y)? 0 : x? 1 : -1;
    });
    
    console.log(a);
```

You must return 0 when a and b both have the same value, -1 if a is true and 1 otherwise.

Comment: Even shorter: a.sort(function(x, y) { return y - x });

Comment: the array that I am sorting is not as simple as the one I posted. Check my edit

Comment: @PCoelho, consider using Joe's solution. It works and is more concise.

Comment: @JoeFrambach Can you explain how that works or point me to a thread that explains the syntax for something like that?

Comment: Thanks for this, now if you were wanting to now sort the list of `true` values a second time, would it be a simple case of first sorting them alphabetically, then the true false sort?

Comment: @AdamMoisa Joe's solution works because of something called Type Coercion. Basically, the JS engine will notice you're trying to do a math operation (subtraction) on `boolean` values, so it'll convert `false` into `0` and `true` into `1`.

Comment: @SilvestreHerrera that’s cool and makes sense. Thanks for that!

Comment: @SilvestreHerrera No, there is no Type Coercion in the above example. According to the docs, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort, the compareFunction needs to return -1,0, or 1, which will determine an element's position. 

The code example above uses nested ternary statements, which, in the case of the uncommented 'truthy values first' example says the following (in english) if x and y are strictly equal return 0, otherwise if x is true return -1 if not return 1;

Comment: my solution was list.sort((a, b) => a.booleanProperty && !b.booleanProperty ? 1 : -1); Iäm using typescript so i cannot use - operator.

Comment: a.sort((a, b) => Boolean(b.property) - Boolean(a.property));

Comment: `y - x` does not work in TS with boolean, causes `The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type`

Comment: @coler-j in *TypeScript* you can convert booleans to numbers by adding `+` at the beginning. for example `+array.includes((el) => el.x === foo.x)) - ... `

Comment: In case `y - x` doesn't work for any reason, another method would be to convert `boolean` to `Number` `array.sort((x, y) => y ? 1 : 0 - x ? 1 : 0`

Answer (score 80):

To prevent implicit type conversion (which languages like TypeScript don't like), you can use `Number()` to explicitly convert the boolean to a number:

```js
a = [false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false];
a.sort(function(x, y) {
   return Number(x) - Number(y);
});
console.log(a);
```

Or using arrow functions:

```js
a = [false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false];
a.sort((x, y) => Number(x) - Number(y));
console.log(a);
```

Comment: One caveat: this sort compare function will not work with 'undefined` values in input array

Answer (score 51):

a simpler way:

```
a = [{xx:true},{xx:false},{xx:true},{xx:false},{xx:true},{xx:false},{xx:true},{xx:false},{xx:true},{xx:false},{xx:true},{xx:false},{xx:true},{xx:false},{xx:true},{xx:false},{xx:true},{xx:false}];

a.sort(function(a,b){return a.xx-b.xx});

console.log(a);
```

you can call a.reverse() after the sort() if you want it sorted the other way..

EDIT:
edited to reflect updated question of sorting an array of objects instead of an array of booleans.

Comment: @PranavNegandhi: what's wrong is that i answered the question before an edit re-defined it...

Comment: Great, just if you want it sorted the other way, swap the places of `a` and `b` in the sort function, instead of calling `reverse()`.

Answer (score 33):

An array does not have any equal positions, so why not leave away the equals check, and always return either -1 or 1. This approach works well with TS.

```
a.sort(x => x ? -1 : 1)
```

Note: I am a bit concerned how this affects internals of the sort function, but it seems to do the trick.

If you want to reverse sort

```
a.sort(x => !x ? -1 : 1)
```

Comment: perfect solution, i like your minimalistic approach

Comment: In the case when you're sorting objects, this approach doesn't guarantee objects with equal property values (i.e. `a.xx === b.xx`) stay in the same order with respect to each other.

Comment: perfect, brother, very sexy solution

Answer (score 31):

Simple solution:

```
[true, false, true, false].sort((a, b) => b - a)
```

```js
console.log([true, false, true, false].sort((a, b) => b - a));
```

Comment: huh, I did not expect that false - true === -1, thanks for this!

Answer (score 4):

You can actually just do like the following:

```
const sortedData = data.sort(
  (a, b) => Number(b) - Number(a),
);
```

This solution is ok with Typescript has well since the conversion of boolean to number is explicit.

Answer (score 3):

PFB the solution worked for me in Typescript Angular 2 as well,

```
  let a = [{aa:"1",xx:true},{aa:"10",xx:false},{aa:"2",xx:true},{aa:"11",xx:false},{aa:"3",xx:true},{aa:"12",xx:false},{aa:"4",xx:true},{aa:"13",xx:false},{aa:"5",xx:true},{aa:"14",xx:false},{aa:"6",xx:true},{aa:"15",xx:false},{aa:"7",xx:true},{aa:"16",xx:false},{aa:"8",xx:true},{aa:"17",xx:false},{aa:"9",xx:true},{aa:"18",xx:false}];

    //a.sort(function(a,b){return a.xx-b.xx});
    a.sort(function (x, y) {
        // true values first
        return (x.xx === y.xx) ? 0 : x ? -1 : 1;
        // false values first
        // return (x === y)? 0 : x? 1 : -1;
    });
    return JSON.stringify(a);
```

Comment: Thank you for the object oriented way. it worked

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this issue, here is my part, I hope it helps:

```
orders.sort((x, y) => {
   if (x === y) return 0;
   if (x) return -1;
   return 1;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to see if I could do it without using the `? :` operator, just for fun.

**Note**

This works on all sortable data types (strings, numbers), not just raw booleans. I'm not sure if this is faster than `? :` and it's more convoluted. I just get sick of conditionals so it's just personal preference.

```
  var b = [false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
  .sort((a,b) => Number(a > b) * 2 - 1);
```

I can turn that into a utility function and give it a meaningful name:

```
  var sortOrder = {
    asc: (a,b) => Number(a > b) * 2 - 1,
    desc: (a,b) => Number(a < b) * 2 - 1
  }
```

so then I can:

```
  var b = [false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
  .sort(sortOrder.asc);
```

Comment: Note that `sort` works with any number not just -1 or 1. Therefore you could use `(a, b) => Number(a > b) - 0.5` to avoid a multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty simple solution for the comparison function is to check if `a < b`, this gives 0 or 1 when converted to a number.  We then want to map 0 to -1 and 1 to 1.  To do that you can just multiply by 2 then subtract 1.

```
data.sort(function (a, b) {
  return (a < b) * 2 - 1
}
```

or just

```
data.sort((a, b) => (a < b) * 2 - 1)
```

Problem sorted!

If any of your values are `null` they are treated as false (`null*2 === 0`) and any value that is `undefined` will become `NaN` (`undefined*2 === NaN`) which should make it last in either sort direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[true,false,true,false,true];
 
a.sort(function(x, y) {
      a1=x?1:0
      b1=y?1:0
return a1-b1
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A boolean array with enough entries to represent all transitions i.e. true to true, true to false, false to false, false to true.

```
var boolarray = [true, false, true, true, false, false, true]
boolarray.sort( (a,b) => !(a ^ b) ? 0 : a ? -1 : 1)
```

The sort inverts the xor of the inputs. If the inputs are the same then return 0, if they are not then, if the 'a' input is true 'b' must be false so return -1, and vice versa return 1.

'a' and 'b' booleans are sorted when they differ and are ignored when
the same.

To use this method with objects just use the object member names for the sort arguments:

```
var objarray = [{xx:true}, {xx:false}, {xx:true}, {xx:true}, {xx:false}, {xx:false}, {xx:true}]
objarray.sort( (a,b) => !(a.xx ^ b.xx) ? 0 : a.xx ? -1 : 1)
```

Comment: The '^' operator is not allowed for boolean types. Consider using '!==' instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got typescript errors on the  `return (x.xx === y.xx) ? 0 : x ? -1 : 1;`

This is my solution when you want to sort on a boolean property

```
this.mediaList.sort( (a: MediaAutosubscriptionModel, b: MediaAutosubscriptionModel) => {
    let status1: number = a.status === StatusEnum.ACTIVE ? 1 : 0;
    let status2: number = b.status === StatusEnum.ACTIVE ? 1 : 0;
    let comparison: number = 0;
    let direction: number = this.sortDirection === SortDirectionsEnum.ASC ? -1 : 1;
    if (status1 > status2) {
        comparison = direction;
    } else if (status1 < status2) {
        comparison = -1 * direction;
    }
        return comparison;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any ES6 function with time and space optimization -

```js
const data = [false, true, true, true, false, false, false, true];
let lastElementUnchecked;
for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    if(data[i] && lastElementUnchecked !== undefined){
        let temp = data[i];
        data[i] = data[lastElementUnchecked];
        data[lastElementUnchecked] = temp;
        i = lastElementUnchecked;
        lastElementUnchecked = undefined;
    }else{
        if(!data[i] && lastElementUnchecked === undefined){
            lastElementUnchecked = i;
        }
    }
}
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [{ bool: true }, { bool: false }, { bool: false }, { bool: true }];

// Sorting the array to place true values first
const trueValFirst = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  // Converting boolean values to numbers and comparing them
  const boolA = Number(a.bool);
  const boolB = Number(b.bool);
  
  // Sorting in descending order
  return boolB - boolA;
});

console.log(trueValFirst);
```