# Sort array of objects by grouping properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the following array of objects:

**Update: full code**

```
export const fetchInvoices = function (firestore, currentUser) {
    const db = firestore
        .collection("customers")
        .doc(currentUser)
        .collection("subscriptions");
    let invoices = [];
    db.get().then((subscriptionSnapshot) => {
        subscriptionSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            doc.ref.collection("invoices").get().then((invoiceSnapshot) => {
                invoiceSnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
                    let invoice = {
                        "billing_reason": doc.data().billing_reason,
                        "created": doc.data().created,
                        "currency": doc.data().currency,
                        "hosted_invoice_url": doc.data().hosted_invoice_url,
                        "id": doc.id,
                        "invoice_pdf": doc.data().invoice_pdf,
                        "number": doc.data().number,
                        "period_end": doc.data().period_end,
                        "period_start": doc.data().period_start,
                        "status": doc.data().status,
                        "subtotal": doc.data().subtotal,
                        "total": doc.data().total
                    };
                    Object.defineProperty(invoice, 'invoice_id', { value: doc.id });
                    invoices.push(invoice);
                })
            })
        });
    });
    const sortedData = invoices.sort((a, b) => +(b.status === 'open') - +(a.status === 'open'));
    console.log(sortedData);
    return sortedData;
}
```

I want to sort them by the ones with `status: "open"` on the first indexes, and then sort by `created`. Is there a way to do this?

I've been trying to sort only the group of `status: "open"` using `Object.values(obj).includes("open")` to determine if the object has the value and then sort by `truth` as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17387454/13784272).
But still can't even make this "sort by group".

Comment: By group did you mean index of an array? Like objects with "status:open" in [0] and "status:created" in [1] inside the array?

Comment: @VinayKharayat Let's say got 4 objects with "status: open", sort them in the [0], [1], [2], [3] position respectively.

Comment: This looks like an async problem, have you tried logging `invoices` before sorting? I'm guessing it's empty - you're calling `invoices.sort(...` before the `db.get` resolves. see: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @pilchard I do, the array has data and length of 9

Answer (score 1):

Sorting by two different criteria is simply a matter of chaining your criteria with logical OR (||).

In the first example, first by `data.status` converting boolean to an integer and then by `data.created` .

```js
const data = [ { "created": 1, "status": "draft", }, { "created": 5, "status": "paid", }, { "created": 2, "status": "open", }, { "created": 6, "status": "paid", }, { "created": 3, "status": "open", }, { "created": 4, "status": "paid", }, ];

const sortedData = data
  .sort((a, b) => +(b.status === 'open') - +(a.status === 'open') || a.created - b.created);

console.log(sortedData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

or, since you have multiple `status` values, you can create a `sortOrder` map and reference it in your sort callback.

```js
const data = [ { "created": 1, "status": "draft", }, { "created": 5, "status": "paid", }, { "created": 2, "status": "open", }, { "created": 6, "status": "paid", }, { "created": 3, "status": "open", }, { "created": 4, "status": "paid", }, ];

const sortOrder = {
  open: 1,
  paid: 2,
  draft: 3
}

const sortedData = data
  .sort((a, b) => sortOrder[a.status] - sortOrder[b.status] || a.created - b.created);

console.log(sortedData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the example you provide works with your array of objects but not with mine, is there a chance that isn't working because is not a hard-code array? I'm gonna update the full code so you can see how I'm fetching the array

Comment: It's working as expected with the portion of the array you provided in the question.

Comment: please avoid chaining sort. you can just chain the deltas with logical or in a single callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can get objects with open status using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method and sort them using [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method like this.

You can change the order of sort by returning value accordingly in sort function.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "billing_reason": "subscription_create",
        "created": 1614889156,
        "currency": "usd",
        "hosted_invoice_url": "...",
        "id": "...",
        "invoice_pdf": "...",
        "number": "82190D09-0001",
        "period_end": 1614889156,
        "period_start": 1614889156,
        "status": "draft",
        "subtotal": 3900,
        "total": 3900
    },
    {
        "billing_reason": "subscription_cycle",
        "created": 1614890009,
        "currency": "usd",
        "hosted_invoice_url": "...",
        "id": "...",
        "invoice_pdf": "...",
        "number": "82190D09-0002",
        "period_end": 1614890009,
        "period_start": 1614890009,
        "status": "paid",
        "subtotal": 3900,
        "total": 3900
    },
    {
        "billing_reason": "subscription_update",
        "created": 1614890064,
        "currency": "usd",
        "hosted_invoice_url": "...",
        "id": "...",
        "invoice_pdf": "...",
        "number": "82190D09-0003",
        "period_end": 1614890064,
        "period_start": 1614890009,
        "status": "open",
        "subtotal": -1400,
        "total": -1400
    },
    {
        "billing_reason": "subscription_create",
        "created": 1614890802,
        "currency": "usd",
        "hosted_invoice_url": "...",
        "id": "...",
        "invoice_pdf": "...",
        "number": "82190D09-0004",
        "period_end": 1614890802,
        "period_start": 1614890802,
        "status": "paid",
        "subtotal": 3900,
        "total": 3900
    },
    {
        "billing_reason": "subscription_create",
        "created": 1614892003,
        "currency": "usd",
        "hosted_invoice_url": "...",
        "id": "...",
        "invoice_pdf": "...",
        "number": "82190D09-0005",
        "period_end": 1614892002,
        "period_start": 1614892002,
        "status": "paid",
        "subtotal": 3900,
        "total": 3900
    },
    {
        "billing_reason": "subscription_create",
        "created": 1614893124,
        "currency": "usd",
        "hosted_invoice_url": "...",
        "id": "...",
        "invoice_pdf": "...",
        "number": "82190D09-0006",
        "period_end": 1614893124,
        "period_start": 1614893124,
        "status": "paid",
        "subtotal": 3900,
        "total": 3900
    },
    
]

const open = data.filter(d => d.status === "open").sort((a,b) => a.created - b.created);

console.log(open);
```

Comment: filter() doesn't seem to be filtering the value "open", console logs an empty array `length: 0`

Comment: umm , it works fine with array you provided here, see if array has at least one value with status open

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using some great libraries out there this solution might work for you using [underscore](https://underscorejs.org) which is great for situations like this.

Assuming you put your original array into a variable called `data` as in [Solvenc1no's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12173339/solvenc1no) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66506718/2631342) :

```
    const _ = require('underscore');
    const sortedAndGrouped = _.groupBy(_.sortBy(data, "created"),'status');
    console.log(sortedAndGrouped);
```

Which results in this output:

```
{ draft:
   [ { billing_reason: 'subscription_create',
       created: 1614889156,
       currency: 'usd',
       hosted_invoice_url: '...',
       id: '...',
       invoice_pdf: '...',
       number: '82190D09-0001',
       period_end: 1614889156,
       period_start: 1614889156,
       status: 'draft',
       subtotal: 3900,
       total: 3900 } ],
  paid:
   [ { billing_reason: 'subscription_cycle',
       created: 1614890009,
       currency: 'usd',
       hosted_invoice_url: '...',
       id: '...',
       invoice_pdf: '...',
       number: '82190D09-0002',
       period_end: 1614890009,
       period_start: 1614890009,
       status: 'paid',
       subtotal: 3900,
       total: 3900 },
     { billing_reason: 'subscription_create',
       created: 1614890802,
       currency: 'usd',
       hosted_invoice_url: '...',
       id: '...',
       invoice_pdf: '...',
       number: '82190D09-0004',
       period_end: 1614890802,
       period_start: 1614890802,
       status: 'paid',
       subtotal: 3900,
       total: 3900 },
     { billing_reason: 'subscription_create',
       created: 1614892003,
       currency: 'usd',
       hosted_invoice_url: '...',
       id: '...',
       invoice_pdf: '...',
       number: '82190D09-0005',
       period_end: 1614892002,
       period_start: 1614892002,
       status: 'paid',
       subtotal: 3900,
       total: 3900 },
     { billing_reason: 'subscription_create',
       created: 1614893124,
       currency: 'usd',
       hosted_invoice_url: '...',
       id: '...',
       invoice_pdf: '...',
       number: '82190D09-0006',
       period_end: 1614893124,
       period_start: 1614893124,
       status: 'paid',
       subtotal: 3900,
       total: 3900 } ],
  open:
   [ { billing_reason: 'subscription_update',
       created: 1614890064,
       currency: 'usd',
       hosted_invoice_url: '...',
       id: '...',
       invoice_pdf: '...',
       number: '82190D09-0003',
       period_end: 1614890064,
       period_start: 1614890009,
       status: 'open',
       subtotal: -1400,
       total: -1400 } ] }
```

Comment: It's not quite the result I'm looking for, as you can see in the array i'm providing the first index [0] has status "draft". followed by status "paid" then "open". I want objects with status "open" to be in the first indexes 0, 1, 2... if there are more than one as it could be a possibility.