# Array.sort() on multiple properties

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array, `productData` with multiple properties. This is how I currently sort the array by `monthlyCost`, ascending.
How can I modify this to sort all items by a boolean property `isPromoted`, followed by `monthlyCost`?
My array should start with all items where `isPromoted == true` sorted by `monthlyCost`, then all items where `isPromoted == false` sorted by `monthlyCost`.

```
    productData.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.monthlyCost > b.monthlyCost) {
        return 1;
      } else if (a.monthlyCost < b.monthlyCost) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
```

Comment: if `isPromoted` is not equal - then return either `1` or `-1` - if it is equal, then return the result of your existing comparison

Comment: -Equal to what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Comment: and [Javascript sort array of objects by a boolean property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387435/javascript-sort-array-of-objects-by-a-boolean-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this callback:

```
productData.sort((a, b) => +b.isPromoted - +a.isPromoted || a.monthlyCost - b.monthlyCost);
```

The unary plus is optional in plain JavaScript, but in a TypeScript context, you'll need to be explicit about the conversion to number and apply `+`.

Comment: So why is b minus a for `isPromoted` but a minus b for `monthlyCost`?

Comment: Because you want true to come before false, while in numerical order, false (0) would come before (1). So by reversing the expression the order will be as you wish it to be.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm now trying to throw in another property to sort, `promotionLevel` which is either 1 or 2. Adding this in to your expression, `productData.sort((a, b) => +b.isPromoted - +a.isPromoted || a.promotionLevel - b.promotionLevel || a.monthlyCost - b.monthlyCost);` doesn't seem to be working as I expect. Can you tell what I'm doing wrong? (I want promotionLevel 1 to come before 2)